# Is there a way to erase (empty out) the ScriptDb database?

Tags: database, google-apps-script

While I was experimenting with ScriptDB I ended up with over 6000 records. When I tried to remove the items one by one or with `removeBatch()` I always run into the execution time limit removing only about 100 records. Clearly tyhrough this method it takes a looong time and lots of headache to remove all the records from the db.

Is there a better way to reset the db?

(For now I just made a copy of my script effectively abandoning the bloated db.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there seems to be an optimal solution, if we read the section [Common Patterns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/patterns) - [Delete all items in the database](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/patterns?#delete_all_items_in_the_database), we read:

> This script will delete all data from the database. If the database
>   contains a large amount of data, the script may exceed the maximum
>   execution time limit and terminate prematurely. However, you can run
>   it again as necessary until the database is empty.

Comment: Thank you. In the above case this means running the script **60x**, which is quite a pain. If there isn't anything better, the next best option is abandoning the db and letting Google figure out what to do with all that data.

Comment: Set `deleteAll()` up as a timed trigger, running every 5 minutes say, and leave it overnight.